# Saving recorded Voice in Flex using as3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying save the recorded voice locally in my file system using flex and as3.
I am successful in recording voice and playback again. I am using web application prospective in Flex.
Here I noticed that if I used windowed application, I am successfully saving voice record in my system(using adobe air file system). 
Pleas let me know the process of saving recorded file.

Answer (score 2):

You can save VoiceRecord in [ByteArray](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) on Flex Side, and send this ByteArray to Server and save there in File or Database

Comment: One thing to remember, there is a memory limit.  I can't remember what it is offhand.  When you use `ByteArray` this is all stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

[`FileReference.save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29), but it has to be converted to `ByteArray`

Answer (score 0):

There is also a open source alchemy c++ plugin someone built for flash that can encode it to an mp3 on the client.  Would probably be of great use to you: https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy